# How can I Integrate quickbooks's java sdk into android app?

Tags: java, android, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I want integrate and use `Quickbooks` APIs in my android app. What is the proper way to do it?

I have tried and browsed so many things about `Quickbooks sdk` but nothing I found.

So, How can I allow my android app to do api calls with the `Quickbooks` live `APIs` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Quickbooks Android SDK. There are many different SDKs, as you can see here: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/sdks-and-samples

An idea is to host a NodeJS server that deals with the communication with your Quickbooks infrastructure. Then, in the same NodeJS server, expose a set of APIs you have developed yourself that represents the functionality of your Android app.

For example, for the Create Account Quickbook API call, you wrap it with an API you develop yourself and get your Android app to call that specifically.

Comment: Hey @Felipe Caldas thanks for your answer. Can you please give me more information about it?

Comment: Have you ever developed any Android app and NodeJS before?

Comment: Hi, @Felipe Caldas  Yes I have developed many android app but not aware with NodeJS yet.

Comment: NodeJS would be your server. It doesn't have to be NodeJS though, they also have libraries for Python, Java, Ruby, PHP, .NET... any of these technologies could be your server. Choose any that you have experience with.
The mobile app then calls your server for all the server side functionality that you want and it returns the results to be displayed in the app. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Felipe Caldas for your valuable replay. I will try this.